# Which templating framework should I use in a PhoneGap application using JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

I need a javascript templating framework to help creating my detail pages in a mobile application built using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.  I plan to release the application natively on iPhone, and Android.

I have been reading through the jQuery UI wiki about [template comparisions](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/41375604/Template-Comparison) and can't make a conclusive decision on which framework to use.  With the current templating [plugin not making it passed beta](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/) which framework is most likely to still be around in the next couple of years, and be a good choice to start using in a new application today?

Comment: “which framework is most likely to still be around in the next couple of years” – this is impossible to know. Before April, I'd have answered “the official jQuery plugin”.

Comment: I personally use Mustache - fast, easy and just about templating (the other Binding solutions I find to be an overkill for my usage)

Answer (score 1):

[KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) is what I'd go with.  It fits quite well with jQuery since it's templating engine is built on the jQuery template plugin.

It also allows you the ability to two-way bind dom elements to a JavaScript ViewModel object of your choosing.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'll check out knockout

Comment: @rabs - sure - templating is actually one of the least impressive things knockout does.  I was really amazed when I started to use it